# Code clean-up feature in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

As we all know that there's a small brush button for code cleanup in Visual Studio. I have recently switched (still checking out) to VS Code, and I can't find this option in it. Any ideas?

Comment: what does it do: **code cleanup**

Comment: it removes unused libraries, variables, applies formatting and more.

Comment: it is never to late to write an extension that does this, formatting we already have